Different types of Dark energy and conservation of energy
According to this Sean Carroll article, and other threads in here, depending on your definition of energy, dark energy does not violate conservation of energy.  My question is if this is true regardless of the type of dark energy (e.g cosmological constant, quintessence, etc.).

I think you have misunderstood Carroll's article. He is actually saying that energy on cosmological scales is not conserved, but this is not unexpected. "When the space through which particles move is changing, the total energy of those particles is not conserved ... I personally think it’s better to forget about the so-called “energy of the gravitational field” and just admit that energy is not conserved, ... Energy isn’t conserved; it changes because spacetime does."

"spacetime changes" is a super misleading way to understand energy non-conservation, though...

He says that some people do prefer to say that energy is conserved in a expanding universe. "We all agree on the science; there are just divergent views on what words to attach to the science. In particular, a lot of folks would want to say “energy is conserved in general relativity, it’s just that you have to include the energy of the gravitational field along with the energy of matter and radiation and so on.”
